# 400 from elasticsearch when submitting POST request with "_bulk" end point

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I've successfully managed to submit a bulk POST request using the `elasticsearch` module.

But I want to do everything NOT using this module, just using the `requests` module.

I'm having problems when I try to do a POST with the `_bulk` end point. This is the code, where `post_object` is a string of concatenated `json.dumps(...) + '\n'` of the individual documents for populating the index. NB `url` is simply 'http://localhost:9200/docs'.

```
print(f'post_object:\n{json.dumps(post_object, indent=2, default=str)}')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}        
params = {'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}                
response = requests.post(f'{url}/_bulk', data=json.dumps(post_object, default=str) + '\n', headers=headers, params=params)        
print(f'response.json() {response.json()}')
```

This gives:

```
response.json() {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], 
expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]'}], 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]'}, 'status': 400}
```

I had previously tried making `post_object` a list of individual JSON `dict`s... But this gives 400 for another reason:

```
response.json() {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], 
expected START_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]'}], 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]'}, 'status': 400}
```

... does anyone know what sort of "START_OBJECT" `requests` wants to find with this `_bulk` end point?

NB there are various pages devoted to this, e.g. [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-send-json-data-to-elastic-search/143506/3) or [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/docs-bulk.html). I appear to have to submit a string as the `data` param, apparently with some metadata element, and with new lines in the right places. I also apparently have to set the header "Content-type" to "x-ndjson", which I've now done... but I'd just like a simple example, ideally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. NB version of ES is 7.12, Python 3.9.4.

Just thought I'd leave this here to save someone else half an hour's wasted time.

Yes, the use of "Content-type" "x-ndjson" turns out to be essential. It is indeed necessary to submit a string as the `data` parameter. Thus:

```
post_object_str = ''
for num, obj in enumerate(  ... 
    # iteration loop creating the dicts to prepare the ES documents

    dict_doc = {}
    # fill this with your fields, e.g.:
    dict_doc['interesting_data'] = 'something'
    dict_doc['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    # NB you get a complaint if you try to include the "_id" field not as "metadata"
    post_object_str += f'{{"index": {{"_id": "{str(num)}"}}}}\n'
    post_object_str += json.dumps(dict_doc, default=str) + '\n'

# see what it looks like    
print(f'post_object_str:\n{post_object_str[:400]}')
        
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-ndjson'}        
response = requests.post(f'{url}/_bulk', data=post_object_str, headers=headers)
# examine the response...
print(f'post response.json():\n{json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)}')
```

200: index populated in a flash. Beautiful.